# Selecting specific header from json to save in curl

Tags: json, curl

So I have a batch file where I get a json from a web service.

```
"images": [
    {
      "classifiers": [
        {
          "classes": [
            {
              "class": "donald",
              "score": 0.980513
```

In the json there's a header called "class" which is the only thing I want to save to a file called payload.txt.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is actually wrapped in {} (not valid json as-is) then piping to jq would be the simplest option

```
jq .images[].classifiers[].classes[].class
```

Comment: So to then save this would i just do:
jq .images[].classifiers[].classes[].class -o payload.txt ?

Comment: curl -s file:///Users/me/test.txt | jq .images[].classifiers[].classes[].class > payload.txt